# Windows IoT app deployment locally gives app activation error

Tags: c#, windows, windows-10, windows-10-iot-core

I am trying to start with app development for Windows IoT core. I have created a background task project and added some code but when I try to deploy locally (Windows 10 10547 with developer options activated) I get the error message:

> Unable to activate Windows Store app 'prenresearch-uwp_1bs3s1m4g92em!App'. The activation request failed with error 'There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper'.

Has anyone experienced that before?

Regards

Comment: Hi Kevin. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Not really...I haven't used IoT Core and moved to Linux in the meantime for the project I am working on (I would have loved to do it with IoT core but then there isn't much support from libraries anyway)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows IoT Core Background applications are IoT applications only. 
They can only be run on Windows IoT Core. They are meant to replace services since only one application can run (fullscreen) at a time on Windows IoT Core.

[image: project templates]

If you want an application that runs everywhere (desktop, mobile, iot, xbox...), your only choice is the Blank App template from the Universal section.

By default, the application will run on the local machine. Do not forget to select "remote machine" as the debug target to let Visual studio deploy and start the application on the IOT board.

[image: debug target]

You can use the WindowsIotCoreWatcher application to get the IP address of your IOT device if Visual Studio does not detect it automatically.

Comment: I do not try to run them on my PC, Visual Studio however activates them for some reason.

Comment: The default target when running applications is always the local machine, you should change it to remote machine. I've updated my answer.